# mpdf version 6 crash svg image on centos

Tags: php, pdf, svg, mpdf

Hi I am trying to download SVG to PDF using mPDF. The below code works good on windows 7. But when I upload the codes to a cent OS server the PDF download but the image crashes. I have this error in my page.

> warning:
>   file_put_contents(/var/www/tools/ocap/sites/all/modules/maxim/mss_dev/ocap/mpdf/tmp/_tempSVG4109055c06684e6f5c1.85086712_0.svg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/tools/ocap/sites/all/modules/maxim/mss_dev/ocap/mpdf/mpdf.php
>   on line 32022

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();   

// send the captured HTML from the output buffer to the mPDF class for processing
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<svg width="360" height="180">
                    <circle  cx="180" cy="45" r="12"/>
                </svg>');

//$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);  

$mpdf->Output("sample.pdf","D");

exit;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your webserver have permissions to write in the tmp folder?

Comment: hi sir im just a newbie, can i ask how can i check if i have a permission to write in webserver? again i am sorry for a newbie question